# Make PDF reports in Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf, charts, reporting

All the PDF libraries for Perl seem a bit barbaric -- stuck in the 1980's. You have to specify PostScript points to do layout. Java has JasperReports, Ruby has Prawn, and Python has ReportLab. Is there a non-extinct library/module that will let me make a nice looking PDF in less than a week of coding? (I'm a little frustrated by PDF::API2, PDF::Table, etc.) I don't want to generate HTML and convert it. Perl is ideal for reporting, but the main report file format is not available in a usable way. What libraries do people use?

I need:

- tables
- charts (Images)
- color
- formatting (ideally automatic, not pixel by pixel)
- headers / footers

I'm slightly open to wrapping external (non-Perl) open source tools, if absolutely needed. But not really interested in a major Java server approach. For the bounty, I want a pure Perl approach, since I want to run this on a server that I can't add more than modules to. If you have a public example that works well, please point me to it.

Comment: Boy this is a great question.  I have the same requirements and I tried everything in CPAN that I could find.  Finally gave up and learned enough Python to use ReportLab. Would love to get this back to Perl.

Comment: Could ReportLab be used through [`Inline::Python`](http://p3rl.org/Inline::Python)?

Comment: It seems the Inline modules are not being maintained right now, but Inline::Python did work, even though Inline::Ruby did not pass the most basic tests -- it was developed for Perl 5.5 and I'm using a very recent 5. But thanks, ReportLab looks like a good idea if pure Perl fails...

Comment: @sventech, the Inline Modules are very separate, even if Inline::Ruby fails, that doesn't say much about Inline::Python. The basic framework which does the heavy lifting is the [`Inline`](http://p3rl.org/Inline) module, which was last updated in Feb 2011. In fact Inline::Python shows updated in July 2011. I think there is no need to fret.

Comment: @JoelBerger Yes, it should be fine. From my initial look at CPAN I thought they were developed by the same person and had not been updated. It seems Google results end up at an old version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If LaTeX is too big, perhaps one could use [`Inline::Python`](http://p3rl.org/Inline%3a%3aPython) to wrap ReportLab, that everyone seems to like so much (I haven't used it and am not too proficient at Python).

Edit 3:
Here is Edit 2, except split into a modular style, if people like it (and if it is an kind of robust) perhaps I can publish to CPAN. For now place the `.pm` file in a file structure like `Inline/Python/ReportLab.pm` somewhere in your `@INC` (the script's own base directory is usually in `@INC`).

```
# Inline/Python/ReportLab.pm
package Inline::Python::ReportLab;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp;

use Inline::Python qw/py_eval/;
our @ISA = 'Inline::Python::Object';

sub import {
  py_eval('from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas');
}

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $filename = shift || croak "Must specify file name to contructor";
  return bless(Inline::Python::Object->new('__main__', 'Canvas', $filename), $class);
}

1;
```

Then a script could be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Inline::Python::ReportLab;

my $c = Inline::Python::ReportLab->new('hello.pdf');
$c->drawString(100,100,"Hello World");
$c->showPage();
$c->save();
```

Edit 2:
While Edit 1 is still of interest, it seems (tell me if I am incorrect!) that I have figured out how to create an instance of 'Canvas' and expose its methods directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Inline::Python qw/py_eval/;

py_eval('from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas');

my $c = Inline::Python::Object->new('__main__', 'Canvas', 'hello.pdf');
$c->drawString(100,100,"Hello World");
$c->showPage();
$c->save();
```

---

Edit 2/3: This portion is left as an example of a more manual interface. I think Edits 2/3 give a better interface which leaves the heavy lifting to the original Python class without (too much) wrapping.

Edit 1: I have now exposed some of the functionality by manually hacking in the methods. This means that for every method one wants to use, a wrapper method must be added. While this is already a feasible solution, I wonder if there isn't some easier way to expose the entire python 'canvas' class, but for now this is where I am:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Inline Python => <<END_PYTHON;
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

class Canvas:
  def __init__(self,filename):
    self.canvas = canvas.Canvas(filename)
  def drawString(self,x,y,text):
    self.canvas.drawString(x,y,text)
  def save(self):
    self.canvas.showPage()
    self.canvas.save()

END_PYTHON

my $c = Canvas->new('hello.pdf');
$c->drawString(100,100,"Hello World");
$c->save();
```

Comment: Thanks, Joel. That is certainly promising. I'll still hope a bit for a pure Perl solution, but your idea seems to work well.

Comment: Thanks, Joel, for your hard work and ingenuity. I believe it might be very helpful to put such a thing on CPAN, if you just add the major objects which need to be accessed. But for me, your code is very likely a good solution. I'm going to look more carefully at how it works for my purpose.

Comment: @sventech, which other objects would need constructors? I have already begun putting the CPAN module together.

Comment: platypus,lib,graphics,rl_config -- not sure how to handle page sizes, units and styles which are set with an import...
http://www.eecho.info/Echo/python/getting-started-with-reportlab-tutorial/
http://www.protocolostomy.com/2008/10/22/generating-reports-with-charts-using-python-reportlab/

Comment: Assuming you are the only sventech from Dallas, I have added you as a collaborator on the new [GitHub project](https://github.com/jberger/Inline-Python-ReportLab). Hack away and together maybe we can make this work.

Answer (score 10):

Using Perl, generate [LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX), perhaps using [Template::Toolkit](http://p3rl.org/Template%3a%3aToolkit), then call the compiler, either TeXLive or MikTeX or whatever distribution you need for your OS. There is an extension called [Template::LaTeX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template%3a%3aLatex), though you probably don't need it, which manages the build process.

LaTeX has support for all the things you need. Tables get a little interesting but there are some modern table packages which ease things (I think that its called `ltxtable`). For charts (do you mean diagrams) there is a sub language called `TikZ` which is spectacularly powerful.

This really is a very easy workflow, especially if you want the results to be similar every time (i.e. can use a template). In fact it really is not unlike creating HTML from a template and serving it to a browser.

Another benefit of this is that the template (and prepared source) will be portable should you need to build a report in another language.

Comment: Thanks, Joel. I have been thinking about that, since I'm comfortable with LaTeX, but it has a large overhead -- I need to generate a lot of reports.

Comment: If you are already comfortable with LaTeX then I think it is def. the way to go. Whenever I recommend this workflow, I worry that LaTeX is going to be the barrier.

Comment: From an old answer on something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017157/pdf-file-generation-in-perl-is-there-a-primer-to-get-one-started/6023730#6023730 certainly I would recommend templating over what I do there, but it is possible

Comment: I think LaTeX is too computationally intensive for a server environment, and I can't really put it on the machine I want to run my code on. If nothing else works I might have to beg them to install it or something else. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

After much thought and experimentation, I ended up writing a lot of code to wrap PDF::API2. Unfortunately this was an internal project within a company so not going to be released open source, but frankly I'd recommend using a different language (Python / Ruby), perhaps passing the data through with JSON or something. My end result is efficient, but it required a lot of coding. There is a refactoring of PDF::API2 underway on CPAN but it seems to be stalled.

Comment: Interesting to hear what your result was. If you've looked you'll see that I didn't take my idea much further, it was too hard to manage as I wrote it. That said I have done some work adapting Mojo::Template to generate LaTeX. Personally I think that LaTeX is the real answer for PDF generation in any language. Cheers and congrats.

Comment: Also, on occasion companies have donated code to the Perl community. If you could perhaps just ask about it, I'm sure many others would benefit! Just thought I would say that :-)