# How can I produce a PDF file using data in an XML file, in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, pdf

Hi how can I read this information using template toolkit

```
 $var1= {  
  'STC'=>[
     {
        'gym'=>{
              'hyd'=>{
                   'com'=>[
                        'dr'=>'1', 
                         'typ'=>'z',
                          'bemo'=>{
                               'bm'=>'1',
                                'typ'=>'x',
                                'col'=>'red'
                                 }
                               } 
                            {
                          'dr'=>'12', 
                         'typ'=>'a',
                          'bemo'=>{
                               'bm'=>'25',
                                'typ'=>'p',
                                'col'=>'red'
                                 }
                            } 
                         {
                          'dr'=>'23', 
                         'typ'=>'k',
                          'bemo'=>{
                               'bm'=>'22',
                                'typ'=>'w',
                                'col'=>'blue'
                                 }
                            } 
                          {
                          'dr'=>'3', 
                         'typ'=>'s',
                          'bemo'=>{
                               'bm'=>'9',
                                'typ'=>'B',
                                'col'=>'green'
                                 }
                            } 

                          }
                       }
                      ]
                     };
```

I am not able to get this type of complex data , Remaining everything I solved and I am getting output as I want but this problem suffers me.please help me.

Comment: you should leave your original question intact, and append new developments. Therefore if someone else has another idea they can help you. LaTeX is by no means the only way to solve your problem, it is just how I would seeing as I know Perl and LaTeX.

Comment: @joel, could you tell how to overcome this error "pdflatex not recognized as a internal or external command, operable program or batch file. while i am running your code after all bugs cleared.

Comment: @David Fullerton, why close the one that was asked and answered first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so you have some data, what do you expect it to look like? At the risk of sounding snarky, you could simply open in a text editor and print pdf or save as rtf. Clearly this isn't what you mean.

You need to format the data somehow. Then the conversion will simply be the application of that your data to that format.

As I mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534904/make-pdf-reports-in-perl/7535061#7535061), you could make a LaTeX template and fill it in with your data and [`Template::Toolkit`](http://p3rl.org/Template::Toolkit) and compile using a LaTeX compiler. This would get you a PDF.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Fast;
use Template;

my $xml = <<'XML';
 <student>
      <number>24</number>
      <education>bachelors</education>
      <specialization>computers </specialization>
     -<address>
         <house_number="128"/>
         <street name="xxxx"/>
           <proddutoor/>
      <address/>
     -<details>
          <name="clar"/>
          <age="20"/>
         <sex="m"/>
       </details>
</student>
 <student>
      <number>23</number>
      <education>ph.d.</education>
      <specialization>physics </specialization>
     -<address>
         <house_number="128"/>
         <street name="xxxx"/>
           <proddutoor/>
      <address/>
     -<details>
          <name="joel"/>
          <age="20"/>
         <sex="m"/>
       </details>
</student>
XML
my $xml_hash = xml2hash $xml;

my $template = Template->new();

my $filename = 'output.tex';

#I think the following is a holdover from a previous version
#as I cannot check right now, I will leave as a comment:
#open my $fh, '>', $filename;

$template->process(\*DATA, $xml_hash, $filename)
    || die "Template process failed: ", $template->error(), "\n";

system( "pdflatex $filename" );

__DATA__
\documentclass{article}

\title{Roster}
\author{pavani}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

[% FOREACH st IN student %]
Student [% st.number %] is a [% st.specialization %] [% st.degree %] student.

[% END %]

\end{document}
```

N.B. `XML::Fast` even does surprisingly well against your poorly formatted XML :)

Comment: Your information is still xml in a perl hash, so you will still need to parse with an XML library. To see what the resultant hash looks like use `Data::Dumper`: so add `use Data::Dumper;` to the top, and do `print Dumper $xml_hash;` If you read the Template library's documentation, it is fairly clear what I have done. Remember SO is not a "please write my code for me site". Give it a try, I will help you if you have specific questions.

Comment: you may use anything capable of converting an XML to a hash. And yes you will need to install `Template`, as well as a LaTeX compiler. I recommend MikTeX on windows

Comment: Those look like XML format errors, thats on you. The DATA used only once: you did include the entire script right? including the line `__DATA__` and everything after? Thats where your LaTeX template is.

Comment: SO is for programmers asking specific questions, not for asking for someone to write the entire code. I'm willing to write it for you, on a freelance basis, if you want.

Comment: Install [MikTeX](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup). Note: not the portable edition

Comment: Did you reboot? In a command line, can you run `pdflatex`? Beyond that, I run TeXLive on Linux, so I can't help too much

Comment: it looks like compound variables should work:https://metacpan.org/module/Template::Manual::Variables#Compound-Variables

Comment: I studied as you suggested document and I tried i got some result still some problem is there I am getting frist elements only can you uggest me how to get second elements .I edited my post you can see clearly.

Comment: I think this is probably worthy of a new question as it now is beyond the original scope of the question. It is also beyond my knowledge of Template::Toolkit, which is essentially a different language from Perl and LaTeX. Good luck, I hope someone can help you. My only other thought would be to flatten the so that each entry contains only basic key-value pairs. And once again, when you edit a question, leave the old stuff, that way people know how you arrived at where the question currently stands

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing how your XML looks like, I can give you only a very general advice. Use XSLT to transform your XML to the [docbook](http://www.docbook.org) format. (For XSLT, you can either use a Perl module [XML::XSLT](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3a%3aXSLT) or an external XSLT processor like [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html)). You can do this also without XSLT, for example, [using the DOM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-domprl/).

For docbook, there exist tool chains for going to RTF or PDF. For RTF, you will need something like [openjade](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/DocBook-OpenJade-SGML-XML-HOWTO/)

For PDF, use [docbook stylesheets](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/1.75.1/doc/) to transform to FO and use [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) for creating PDF.

Most of the latter steps can be done using some simple shell scripts; you can use Perl instead if you prefer that.

Of course, there are also a lot of commercial solutions for what you are asking here, depending on the platform you are using (which you did not mention). Here, for example, is [a FO-to-RTF converter](http://www.xmlmind.com/foconverter/).

And if your XML is quite simple and you just expect a very simple RTF, you can do that conversion by writing your own XSLT scripts, like in [this example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/david_bennett/archive/2005/06/29/407066.aspx).

(ok, that's not Perl, but since it is mostly XSLT, it should be easy for you to port this).

Comment: I posted my xml data what does it look like and i have large file same like that, i mean more number of students with same format.Now can you suggest me.