# In Perl, how can I produce a PDF file using data in an XML file?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I produce a PDF file using data in an XML file, in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776629/how-can-i-produce-a-pdf-file-using-data-in-an-xml-file-in-perl)

I have xml tags that stored in a hash as shown below.

```
$var1={
     'stud.xml'={ 
                '24'=>'<address>
                        <streetname="xxxx"/>
                         <housenum="138"/">
                        </address>'
                 '20'=>'<address>
                       <streetname="xxxx"/>
                        <housenum="110"/">
                       </address>'
                     }...........
```

now I need to convert into pdf by using perl script. I searched and I found PDF::API2 is best module to convert into pdf. After reading module I am able to create new pdf file and set some settings like font, format,like....but I can't understand how to process this xml data into pdf.

Comment: There isn't a magical "convert XML to PDF" button.  How do you want your data to be displayed in the PDF?

Comment: reasking wont change the answer, you need to understand what I told you here http://stackoverflow.com/q/7776629/468327

Comment: @Jack Maney, I need to display data like student number and his address below.

Comment: @pavani - Then simply extract the data that you need and print it out.

Comment: print in pdf by using PDF::API2 module or I need to extract and create latex template using perl and then I need to write something latex template and compile with pdflatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a LaTeX template, populate the template using the data, and then run `pdflatex` on it.

Note that the XMLish thing you posted is not helpful. Either post the actual XML or the Perl data structure.

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings; use strict;
use HTML::Template;
use XML::Simple;

my $xml = <<'EO_XML';
<students>
    <student id="24">
        <address>
            <streetname val="xxxx"/>
            <housenum val="138" />
        </address>
    </student>
    <student id="20">
        <address>
            <streetname val="xxxx"/>
            <housenum val="110" />
        </address>
    </student>
</students>
EO_XML

my $data = XMLin($xml)->{student};

my @loop_data;

for my $student (values %$data) {
    my $address = $student->{address};
    push @loop_data, {
        HOUSENUM => $address->{housenum}{val},
        STREETNAME => $address->{streetname}{val},
    };
}

my $tmpl = HTML::Template->new(filehandle => \*DATA);

$tmpl->param(STUDENTS => \@loop_data);
$tmpl->output(print_to => \*STDOUT);

__DATA__
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<TMPL_LOOP STUDENTS>
<TMPL_VAR HOUSENUM> <TMPL_VAR STREETNAME>

</TMPL_LOOP>
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think its interesting that you suggest the same thing I suggested the last time the OP asked this http://stackoverflow.com/q/7776629/468327

Comment: I think you may have taken me wrongly, I am pleasantly surprised that you came to the same conclusion. I imagined that this was a lot of rigmarole for this task, but it was what I could contribute. That you came to the same conclusion, is interesting!

Comment: @JoelBerger No, I understood where you're coming from, but forgot to add a `:-)` *;-)* Anyway, generating PDF files is a pain -- relegating that to Something Else has been a lifesaver to me in many instances. Heck, I have even written output to spreadsheets and automated printing to PDF/PS.

Comment: @Sinan, thanks for reply. in the above example you created one html template. so same as like I need to create one latex template and run it on pdf latex. which latex is better? i need to instal any latex compiler.

Comment: @Sinan, can you tell me what should this program does, what can I do after running this program. what does it mean <<'EO_XML' and EO_XML. after running this program it printing like \documentclass{article}, \begin{document}, \end{document}. it printing above three statements then next what should I do, please tell me.