# Perl script to print data like this 

Tags: xml, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Perl, how can I produce a PDF file using data in an XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823913/in-perl-how-can-i-produce-a-pdf-file-using-data-in-an-xml-file)

I have one xml file, I extracted some comments and saved in pdf file.I written script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use PDF::API2;
use PDF::API2::Page;
use XML::LibXML::Reader;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file;
open( $file, 'formal.xml');
my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new( IO => $file )
    or die ("unable to open file");

my %nums;
while ($reader->nextElement( 'Number' ) ) {
    my $number = $reader->readInnerXml();
    $reader->nextElement( 'address' ); 
    my $info = $reader->readOuterXml(); 
    $nums{$number} = $info;
}

my $pdf = PDF::API2->new(); 
# $pdf->mediabox('Letter');
my $font = $pdf->corefont('Times-Roman');
my $page = $pdf->page();
$page->mediabox('Letter');

my $cnt = 0;
for my $line (split /\n/, Dumper(%nums)) {
    if ($cnt > 46) {
        $page = $pdf->page();
        $cnt = 0;
    }
    my $text = $page->text();
    $text->font($font,14);
    $text->translate(72, 720-$cnt*14);
    $text->text($line);
    ++$cnt;
}

$pdf->saveas('svr.pdf');
```

when I run this code it extracting and printing extracted tags as it is in pdf file like as shown below.

```
   $VAR1 = '24';
   $VAR2 = '<Address>
            <housenumber="120"/>
           <streetname="xxx"/>
            <information/>
           </Address>';
  $VAR3 = '25';
   $VAR4 = '<Address>
       <housenumber="150"/>
    <streetname="xxx"/>
      <information/>
       </Address>';
     $VAR5 = '27';
     $VAR6 = '<Address>
             <housenumber="140"/>
             <streetname="xxx"/>
             </information>
                </Address>';
```

like that  but i need to print data in pdf like this

```
  number: 24, address information of the student.
     Information:Address,
             housenumber="120",
              streetname="xxx",
               information. 
     number: 25, address information of the student.
     Information:Address,
             housenumber="150",
              streetname="xxx"
              information. 
     number: 27, address information of the student.
     Information:Address,
             housenumber="140",
              streetname="xxx"
               information.
```

I need to print output like this in pdf file. In my Written code I am printing xml tags as it is. What should i do to print like, help me with this script.

Comment: I reformatted your code, since your indentation was all over the place.  Please try to do this yourself in the future -- it makes the code much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use [XML::LibXML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aSimple) instead to parse the XML file and this will allow you to get the content of the either the nodes or the attributes (without the tags).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$reader->copyCurrentNode(1)`](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-1.88/lib/XML/LibXML/Reader.pod#METHODS_EXTRACTING_DOM_NODES) to parse an element and its children into a DOM tree, from which you can then extract the values you want, like this (warning: untested code):

```
my %nums;
while ($reader->nextElement( 'Number' )) {
    my $number = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1)->textContent;

    $reader->nextElement( 'address' ); 
    my $node = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1); 
    my $infohash = {
        house  => $node->getElementsByTagName( 'housenumber' )->[0]->textContent,
        street => $node->getElementsByTagName( 'streetname'  )->[0]->textContent,
    };
    $nums{$number} = $infohash;
}
```

See [XML::LibXML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-1.88/lib/XML/LibXML/Element.pod) for more information on how to extract information from the DOM.

Comment: Hi,i am getting syntax errors at ")[" and at the end "}". and also i need to specify use XML::LibXML::Element.

Comment: Oops, sorry, fixed those syntax errors for you.  Been writing too much JavaScript...

Comment: sorry for asking once again after modification, i am getting error like " can't call method "textContent" on an undefined value at line 23. it means in info hash.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps some of your `<address>` elements contain no `<housenumber>` or `<streetname>` element?  You may need to check for that.  In any case, you should adjust the code to match the structure of your actual XML file.  (The snippets in your example output above don't look like valid XML to me, so I had to guess about what your real data looks like.)