# how to store resultant hash into new file

Tags: xml, perl

Actual problem is my input is xml file ,just sample input look like this

```
<student>
  <number>24</number>
  <education>bachelors</education>
  <specialization>computers </specialization>
  <address>
      <name="michel"/>
     <house_number="128"/>
     <town=proddutoor/>
  </address>   
  </student>
   <student>
  <number>23</number>
  <education>ph.d.</education>
  <specialization>physics </specialization>
 <address>
     <name="clar"/>
     <house_number="12"/>
     <town=kadapa/>
  </address>
   </student>
```

I need to extract information like like this

```
 $var1={
        student=>[
                 {
                'number'=>'24',
                 'education'=>'bachelors',
                 'specilization'=>'computers',
                  'address'=>'name=michel'
                              'house_number=128'
                               'town=proddutoor',
                     }
                   {
                  'number'=>'23',
                 'education'=>'ph.d.',
                 'specilization'=>'physics',
                  'address'=>'name=clar'
                              'house_number=12'
                               'town=kadapa',
                   }
```

I need to print my hash like this and store this hash in new file. I am facing problems with extracting address information.I am not getting address tag elements like this.

Comment: So what have you tried, and what results are you getting?  SO isn't a place where we just write your program for you.

Comment: not that it matters, but are you [pavani](http://stackoverflow.com/users/992215/pavani)? You are using his [data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776629/how-can-i-produce-a-pdf-file-using-data-in-an-xml-file-in-perl/7785246#7785246). If so, please don't create multiple usernames. If not then ignore this.

Answer (score 1):

`Backslash found where operator expected ... near "store_fd \"` is the error you'll get if you have the line

```
store_fd \%hash, $file1;
```

and you have not defined the function `store_fd`.  [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable) does not export `store_fd` by default; you have to ask for it.  It sounds like you didn't.

From some of your comments, it's also possible you might be misspelling the function name.  Perl is case-sensitive; `Store_fd` is a completely separate function from `store_fd`.

Here's a complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Storable qw(store_fd);

my %hash = (key => 'value');

my $file1;
open $file1, '>', "result.stored" or die $!;

store_fd \%hash, $file1;
```

Note that you should not write to a file named `result.xml` using Storable, because Storable does not write XML.  It writes its own format.  If you want to write XML, you can use a different module like [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple) or [XML::Writer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aWriter).  But you'll have to give more details about what you want your XML to look like before I can give you a decent example of that.

Comment: hi I posted my actual problem in the question.@cjm

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using `XML::Simple` library for simple XML manipulation (keep in mind this depends on your exact needs on processing and outputting the XML file).

Comment: I tried but it giving same error like " backslash found where operater expected atc:\libxml.pl line 44 near "store_fd \". (do you need predeclare Store_fd?)

Comment: I mean you don't need Storage if you use XML::Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a file reference like a file name in the store sentence.
Acording the documentation, you can pass the name:

```
store \%nums,'result.xml';
```

or:

```
store_fd \%nums, $file1;
```

Comment: I tried but it giving same error like " backslash found where operater expected atc:\libxml.pl line 44 near "store_fd \".                            (do you need predeclare Store_fd?)